# how to put default value in cells in a row of datagridview in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, random, datagridview

how to put default value in cells in a row of datagridview in vb.net? I have a datagridview in vb.net and I want to put data in cells of a row, I want to put numbers in every cell in a row, from 1 to 31, randomly.
any help would be awesome.
thanks in advance a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used to add a new row with your data to the DataGridView.

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(1, 11, 21, 31)
```

And an existing row can be updated this way.

```
DataGridView1.Rows(0).SetValues(1, 11, 21, 31)
```

You also might want to look into the DefaultValuesNeeded event.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DefaultValuesNeeded
    e.Row.SetValues(1, 11, 21, 31)
End Sub
```